# Как сделать так, чтобы карты появлялись в конкретном порядке, одна за одной?

Tags: c#, unity3d

сейчас карты появляются рандомно из-за этого кода

```cs
public void NewCard()
{
    int rollDice = Random.Range(0, resourseManager.cards.Length);
    LoadCard(resourseManager.cards[rollDice]);
}
```

Comment: В каком _конкретном порядке_?  Вы можете выбрать N карт из колоды в K карт, и отсортировать раздачу в нужном порядке (в зависимости от игры/козырей и т.п.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492880/how-to-make-this-work-without-random-but-in-turn здесь я выложил код, это игра наподобие рейнс...

Comment: Скриншоты - это не код, о чём вам уже написали.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [очередь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=net-6.0) для хранения порядка выдачи карт. К примеру:

```
Queue<int> order = new Queue<int>() { 12, 4, 8, 16}
```

Затем, когда нужно достать карту, доставайте из очереди элемент

```
LoadCard(resourceManager.cards[order.Dequeue()])
```

Но не забывайте про проверку длины, чтобы не пытаться обратиться к пустой очереди.

Comment: Хотелось-бы дополнить информацией с metanit https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.7.php, которая сможет пролить свет, если данная структура является новой для автора. Так же, стоит обратить внимание на Stack https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.8.php. Возможно, он так же поможет решить вашу проблему